# Using AWS SQS to handle a long query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a NodeJS endpoint that receives requests to gather data from a reporting engine. 
To keep the request endpoint light and because some of the reports generated have a few steps (Gather data -> assemble report -> convert to PDF -> Email to relevant person) I want to separate the inbound request from the job itself.

Using AWS.SQS I can accept the request, put the variables into SQS and the respond with a 200 / 201.

What are some of the better practices around picking this job up on the other end?
If I were to trigger a lambda function would I have to wait for that function to complete before 200 / 201 can be sent? or can I:

```
Accept Request ->
Job to SQS -> 
Initiate Lamba function ->
200 Response.
```

Alternatively what other options would be available to decouple the inbound request from the processing itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. Insert the request in your SQS queue and return a 200 response immediately. Have a process on an EC2 server polling the SQS queue and performing the query when it gets a message out of SQS.
2. Invoke a Lambda function asynchronously, passing it the properties needed to perform the query, and return a 200 response immediately. Since you invoked the Lambda function asynchronously your NodeJS code that invoked the Lambda function doesn't wait for the function to complete.
3. An alternative to #2 is to send the request to an SNS topic, and have the SNS topic configured to invoke the Lambda function. This is probably the best method if you are using Lambda, because SNS will retry if the Lambda function fails for some reason.

I don't recommend combining SQS with Lambda because those two services don't integrate very well. SNS on the other hand does integrate very well with Lambda.

Also, you need to make sure your Lambda function invocations can be completed in under 5 minutes since that's currently the maximum time a Lambda function can execute. If you need individual steps to run for longer than 5 minutes you will need to use EC2 or ECS.

I think [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) may be a good fit for your use case.

Comment: Awesome, An asynchronous Lambda function was where I was thinking of going. I can use cloud watch to tell me if a job goes over the 5 min threshold.  - Thank you for your help!